# RedirectView.as_view django and urls.py

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to redirect from urls.py using RedirectView.as_view, but it doesn't work (I mean it doesn't redirect, I stay in the same page). I think the regular expressions used is right. Here is my code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^login/(\w*)', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^index/', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login/tw.+', RedirectView.as_view(permanent=False,   url='index/'))
]
```

I'm trying to redirect from a URL like this one:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/login/tw?oauth_token=THETOKEN&oauth_verifier=OAUTHVERIFIER

Comment: Define "it doesn't work"

Comment: It doesn't redirect, I stay in the same page

Answer (score 2):

`r'^login/(\w*)'` catches `login/tw` before the redirect rule.

Answer (score 0):

You add a slash in front of the url you want to redirect to like this + `app/` in urlpattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^app/login/tw.+', RedirectView.as_view(permanent=False, url='/index/'))
]
```

---

*edit: this is just a guess how *it's not working* :D

*edit2: added `app/` in urlpattern

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm in the same point as before, it doesn't redirect -.-

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what's happening? 

Is this your base urls.py?

Is `app/` also missing in front of `login/tw.+`? I've edited the answer to include that part of url.

Comment: app is my application and this is my applications's urls.py. My main urls.py is useless. I think the main problem is based on in using a httpResponse and I'm returning the Response, I can't render it. I'm using oauth with Authomatic and my code is based on the simple Django example. Again, thank you for your answer @mislav